# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token. Google API Translate

Tags: javascript, php, html, token, translate

I am the beginner, so do not have much experience. 
The task is to translate the blocks of text the user writes.
So html-file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('#some_id').on('click', function(){
    var text_var = JSON.stringify("{$text_without_adv}");
    var own_script = 'gTApi.php';

    $.ajax({
        method: 'post',
        url: own_script,
        data: $.parseJSON(text_var)
    }).done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);       
    });
});
</script>
```

php-file "gTApi.php" (where the magic happens):

```
<?php
  require_once "../../vendor/autoload.php";

  use GuzzleHttp\Client;
  use GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException;

  $text = file_get_contents('php://input');
  $apKey = '**************************';

  $client = new Client(
     array(
        'headers' => array(
           'Accept' => 'application/json'
            )
         )
      );
   try {
      $response =$client->get('https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=' 
      . $apKey
      . '&source=en&target=es&q=' . $text);

   } catch (\Exception $e) {
       echo $e->getMessage();
   }
$response_body = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
echo $response_body['data']['translations'][0]['translatedText'];
```

another php-file:

```
$smarty->assign('text_without_adv', htmlspecialchars((implode(' ', $text_array))));
```

after the page loads I get unexpected token after the first sentence in variable **$text_without_adv** and can't do the translation, nothing happens when I click the button.

For example:

`var text_var = JSON.stringify` ("
***But she had a sweetheart, and he said he would go and get the ball.*** ///**token**/// So he went to the park gate, but 'twas shut; so he climbed the hedge, and when he got to the top of the hedge, an old woman rose up out of the dyke before him, and said, if he wanted to get the ball, he must sleep three nights in the house. He said he would.");

But the main question is that there can be no errors in other posted  texts from other users. I can't understand, 3 different texts from 3 different users have unexpected token, then the next 2 have no error, then the next one has the error and so on. Where could be the problem?

Comment: if you want JSON, then make your php code send JSON - currently you use `json_decode` ... guaranteed not to be JSON

Comment: is this your php variable `$text_without_adv`?

Comment: @Beginner `$text_without_adv` yes, it is assigned in php file

Comment: @JaromandaX could you write an example of what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

In this case you don't need to pass a json instead just pass a `post` data

To do that

First change this line

```
// to stored your php variable in a js variable
var text_var = "<?php echo $text_without_adv; ?>";
```

then

in your ajax

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'post',
    url: own_script,
    data: {
        // just use the declared js variable above which contains your php variable at the first place
        text: text_var
    }
}).done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);       
});
```

and in your php

instead of

```
$text = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

change to

```
$text = $_POST['text'];
```

so your code would be like this

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('#some_id').on('click', function(){
    var text_var = "<?php echo $text_without_adv; ?>";
    var own_script = 'gTApi.php';

    $.ajax({
        method: 'post',
        url: own_script,
        data: {
            text: text_var
        }
    }).done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);       
    });
});
</script>
```

PHP

```
<?php
  require_once "../../vendor/autoload.php";

  use GuzzleHttp\Client;
  use GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException;

  $text = $_POST['text'];
  $apKey = '**************************';

  $client = new Client(
     array(
        'headers' => array(
           'Accept' => 'application/json'
            )
         )
      );
   try {
      $response =$client->get('https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=' 
      . $apKey
      . '&source=en&target=es&q=' . $text);

   } catch (\Exception $e) {
       echo $e->getMessage();
   }
$response_body = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
echo $response_body['data']['translations'][0]['translatedText'];
```

Comment: I get **Status Code:503 Service Unavailable** Form Data: `text:<?php echo $text_without_adv; ?>`

Comment: can you screen shot it

Comment: screenshot of what part do you need? Form Data or Status Code or smth else?